# image insertion in 2 columns

Tags: latex

While inserting a picture in 2 columns in ieee conference template, after compilation a word 'figure' is appearing in new line whereas image is inserted successfully. code is here:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=15cm,height=7cm]{chart.png}
\caption{xyz image}
\label{fig:chart}
\end{figure*}
```

please help!

Comment: Your code is correct. Could you include a complete MWE?

Comment: it is fixed by just removing extra libraries